# C++ different behaviour when trying to assign to const types

Tags: c++

Considering the code

```
(1) Fruit f1{"Orange"};
(2) Fruit f2{"Lemmon"};
(3) const Fruit ff = f1;
(4) ff = f2;
```

C++ compiler complains at line (4) that `Fruit` cannot be assigned to `const Fruit`. But if I write

```
(1) Fruit f1{"Orange"};
(2) Fruit f2{"Lemmon"};
(3) const Fruit* ff = &f1;
(4) ff = &f2;
```

why doesn't the compiler complain at line (4) that `Fruit*` cannot be assigned to `const Fruit*` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between const int\*, const int \* const, and int const \*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)

Comment: Also note that your second example assigns a `const Fruit*` to a `const Fruit*`, since `Fruit*` can implicitly convert to `const Fruit*`

Comment: `const` applies to the thing on its left, unless there is nothing there, then it applies to the thing on its right instead.  So, `const Fruit ff` (aka `Fruit const ff`) means that `ff` is a `const Fruit` object, so it can't be modified. Whereas `const Fruit* ff` (aka `Fruit const * ff`) means that `ff` is a non-const pointer to a `const Fruit` object. The `ff` pointer itself can be modified, but the object it is pointing at cannot be modified through that pointer. Also, a pointer-to-const can point at a non-`const` object, but conversely a pointer-to-non-const cannot point at a `const` object.

Comment: Perfect! I think I understood. Compiler will complain If I write ```Fruit * const ff = &f1; ff = &f2;``` because now ```ff``` is a const pointer to a Fruit.

Comment: `const` qualifies the thing to its immediate left.  (The exception to the rule is when `const` appears first, and then it applies to the thing to its immediate right.)